# Identifying and classifying 2D shapes from a list of x,y coordinates

Tags: python, classification, shapes

Hello StackOverflow community,

I am currently working on a project in which I have a list of points with x and y coordinates as an input. These points form one or sometimes several different shapes on a graph. These shapes can be spherical, elliptical, rectangular, and sometimes irregular. I am looking for a method to identify these shapes from the points.
To give a more concrete example, here is what my input data (set of points) might look like:

```
points = [
    (1, 2),
    (2, 3),
    (3, 4),
    // more points, up to 500...
]
```

Each set of points forms a shape, and I want to determine what that shape is. There could be more than one shape present in the data, and in that case, I want to identify all of them.
I have already tried some basic geometric analysis, but it doesn't handle the irregular shapes very well, and it's not very efficient when there are multiple shapes in the data. I suspect that machine learning, and specifically convolutional neural networks (CNNs), might be a good approach to this problem, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Is a CNN a good approach to this problem, or is there another type of model that would be more suitable? What might the architecture of such a model look like and how would I implement it?

Thank you in advance for your insights and assistance!

Comment: Step 1: describe how you'd identify shapes from points as a human. If you can't do that, then there's nothing to implement, because you have no criteria that you're looking well-fitting algorithms for. Also remember that "a list of points" is a 1D data structure, but if you have "more points, up to 500" then why not just use actual images instead of just coordinates? That way you have fixed-length input, and then yeah, using a neural network to recognize shapes would make sense because that's literally the textbook example of basic neural networks =)

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I had the idea to convert the graph of the points to an image as well, however, there are still two problems: 1) How do I identify multiple shapes and not only one? and 2) Usually, the edges of shapes may be incomplete due to the points. I could imagine that this would lead to problems in the identification process.

Comment: neural networks don't care, they just propagate their weights until it can identify your training shapes.  Blur your points a little to get the NN a margin for error to work with, and off you go. It's why we can recognize small images of handwritten numbers using NN pretty well, despite everyone writing them differently. Alternatively, _don't_ use NN and then you're 100% on the hook for describing what properties of your data define which shapes, so you can use property-appropriate algorithms to classify your data.

Comment: Then would I have to train the NN with multiple different shapes from one set of points or would it be sufficient to just train one shape each time?

Comment: That's not a question for here, that's a question with plenty of answers and tutorials on the web already. Search for how to train a neural net to recognize simple shapes and you should find plenty of material to work off of.